# Проблема с std::string*[] C++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели, память

Никак не могу понять в чём дело.

```
   std::string* array_str0 = new std::string[2];
   std::string* array_str1 = new std::string[2];

   array_str0[0] = "00000000";
   array_str0[1] = "111111111111111111111111";

   memmove(array_str1, array_str0, sizeof(std::string) * 2);

   delete[] array_str0;

   for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       std::cout << array_str1[i] << "\n";
```

Вывод:

```
00000000

0000000════════════════
```

Если убрать delete[] array_str0, то всё работает правильно:

```
00000000
111111111111111111111111
```

С другими типами (int, char) также всё работает правильно. Кто-нибудь может объяснить почему так происходит?

Comment: [If the objects are potentially-overlapping or not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of memmove is not specified and may be undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите - вы просто

```
memmove(array_str1, array_str0, sizeof(std::string) * 2);
```

скопировали не содержимое строк, а скопировали их внутреннее представление - те же указатели на выделенную для содержимого строк память.

Удаляя указатель,

```
delete[] array_str0;
```

вы вызываете деструкторы строк, которые эту память освобождают. Все. Строк больше нет!

Но в `array_str1` лежат указатели на **уже удаленные** строки, и вы обращаетесь к памяти, которая была освобождена - UB!...

Вот так - через `memmove` - сложные типы не копируются, только POD (plain old data, грубо - С-шные типы без указателей) - что вы сами заметили: *С другими типами (int, char) также всё работает правильно.*

Вам надо было копировать примерно так:

```
array_str1[0] = array_str0[0];
array_str1[1] = array_str0[1];
```

А у вас получилось взрывоопасная смесь французского (С++) с нижегородским (С)...

Comment: ага, а sizeof(std::string) * 2 -  это где то 24*2 до 32*2 байт. Там чуточку больше копируется:)

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, я упомянул "те же указатели" - что надо читать как "в том числе", но не "только"..

Comment: Я бы предложил сделать `std::swap` вместо копирования

Comment: интересно, почему sso не отработало

Comment: @KoVadim, думаю ТС спользует `MSVC` а там при отладке оптмизация коротких строк не работает.

Comment: это я знаю. я на gcc/clang прогнал - но оно тоже не хочет

Comment: @KoVadim А наличие sso обязательно, или это зависит от реализации?

Comment: я не видел требований к наличию sso. Но есть упоминания о нем как об объяснении почему "Change: Loosen basic_string invalidation rules"

Comment: Я делал свою собственную реализацию std::vector (В целях обучения) и бил крайне удивлен когда увидел что мои результаты лучше чем у std::vector. Пока не начал тестить с строками. После, я как вы и сказали, сделал по-элементарное копирование. И теперь, результаты тестов, один в один как у std::vector. Я хотел би узнать, нет ли более быстрого способа копировать динамический массив?

Comment: Можно очень быстро и правильно - но только что-то одно :) У вас программа не проходит какие-то временные тесты? Или работает слишком медленно? И вы профилировали ее и точно знаете, что проблема именно в копировании?...

Comment: Да — проблема точно в скорости копирования. Но как я и сказал, скорость такая же, как у std::vector - то-есть вполне приемлема. Но все же, если есть способ сделать лучше, я хотел би его знать.)

Comment: Использовать оптимизацию COW  - copy on write. Т.е. объект не копируется, только указатель на него - пока вы его не изменяете (например, при изменении строки). Только в этом случае создается копия. Естественно, такой указатель вы не должны удалять, и за всем этим нужно следить. Еще вариант - если вы хотите только копировать, но не изменять строки - интеллектуальный указатель типа `shared_ptr`. Но тогда изменение одной строки автоматом отражается в, так сказать, "копии". Но если вам нужна именно копия - которая не зависит от исходной строки - то ничего не поделаешь...

Comment: Да, я читал о COW. Но как я понимаю, там наступают большие проблемы при использовании с разных потоках. Похоже, прийдется оставаться с такой скоростью. Но, она довольно велика, и я этим доволен. Учтивая что мне 15) Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @NeutrinoZh "Я хотел би узнать, нет ли более быстрого способа копировать динамический массив" - есть:) - не делать копирование.